# Sequelize findAll limit with nested Data

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

i have following associations:

```
a hasMany b

b belongsTo c
```

I try to findAll with a limit for the first entry of b

```
var data = await a.findAll({
    where: { name: 'abc' }
    include: [{
      model: b,
      attributes: [],
      include: [{
        model: c
      }]
    }],
    raw: true,
    nest: true
  })
```

this is working fine.

But `b` has many entry's. I just want to have one entry.

So I tried to `limit: 1` within `include model b`.

But this gives me just get the entry's of "a" back

Is there any way to get this going?

Comment: What entry of b do you suppose to be first?